# Function is returning the array not value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function in PHP that is returning the array but not the value.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong

```
function get_current_call_count() {
    //Variable declearation
    $line1="";
    $line2="";
    $total_call_count="";
    $current_call_count="";
    $var=array();
    // Executing shell command to get total number.
    $shell_command = ("/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'core show calls'");
    exec($shell_command,$result,$status);
    //print_r($result);
    $line1=explode(" ",$result['0']);
    $current_call_count=$line1['0'];
    $line2=explode(" ",$result['1']);
    $total_call_count=$line2['0'];
    $var=array("$current_call_count","$total_call_count");
    return($var);
    //echo("Current call count is $current_call_count and Total system call count is $total_call_count");
}
```

Comment: What value are you expecting? You are attaching an Array to `$var` so its obviously that you return the Array.

Comment: @putvande are you saying about this line `$var=array("$current_call_count","$total_call_count");`

Comment: Yes that line is attaching an array to `$var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning array, because you made it so:

```
$var=array("$current_call_count","$total_call_count");
return($var);
```

So all is fine. I suspect that later on you try to use the value returned by this function as non array, so cast occurs and you end with "Array" string. But it's your fault in later code. If you want use certain value from the array, you must get it from there, which is most likely missing in your other code.

Comment: i am using like this `$var=array();
$var = get_current_call_count(); `

Comment: how can i get the values that i get from arrary or how can i split

Comment: try then $var[]=get_current_call_count(); or just $var=get_current_call_count(); without setting $var=array();